# Is there an appropriate use of adjusting class weights for a balanced dataset?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, dataset, convolutional-neural-network

I ask this because I am currently working with a CNN model built for diagnosis of pneumonia. Originally, I followed a notebook on kaggle to build the model and thereby learn what each bit of code is for, etc.
The dataset used was rather imbalanced, with a far greater number of pneumonia cases than normal (healthy) ones. Hence the model.fit class_weight parameter was set to `{0:6.0, 1:0.5}`.
*(0 being normal, 1 being pneumonia)*

Since then, whilst working on the model and making adjustments, I acquired a number of new data to add to the model such that now the dataset is fairly balanced. In fact, I ensure that the data is loaded into the model so that it is exactly balanced, the dataframes used are coded to ensure an equal number of pneumonia and normal cases in the training testing and validation dataframes.

So, accordingly, I am now trying to remove the use of the class_weights parameter as (as far as I understand it) it is not necessary and may impart some bias in the results. However, in doing so, the model no longer seems to improve in accuracy. It essentially stalls on 0.5 indefinitely. Whereas, with the weights applied, I achieve 0.90+ accuracy.

Simply put, is there some reason for this? The code is quite long, but I'm happy to post it if it is deemed required, but I feel like this may be due to my lack of understanding than error in code (as it has otherwise been working fine and as expected). Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For the sake of clarity and understanding, I performed a grid search over possible values for applied weight values. It confirmed an appropriate choice as being `0:~4.0, 1:0.4`, but also suggests `0:1, 1:5.0`.

EDIT 2: For further clarity, a link to a github containing the model code and output files etc. https://github.com/GeeKandaa/ML-Code

Comment: Given the edit, and neural nets being fickle, could this just be random effects of the training?

Comment: As far as my understanding of it goes, I don't believe that's the case here. I performed a gridsearch three times which gave comparable results around the values given in the edit. Further, setting weights to default (0:1,1:1) consistently returned poor validation results.

Comment: Interesting! I don't suppose you could share the data and code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, as this work is part of my dissertation I wanted to double check with my supervisor what I could and could not share at this point. I've added a link to a github containing the code (It is quite long and convoluted, likely not very optimised..) The output data from my gridsearches are contained in Support_Files under base_gridsearch_class_weights#X.json

Comment: Thanks!
I still suspect NN convergence issues: in the results #3 file e.g., in each case with 0.5 accuracy, the confusion matrix has predicted everything to be the same class, and which one depends on the weights.  In the first few grid points, you increase the weights towards the negative class, but after the first two suddenly the network _starts_ predicting the positive class.

Comment: Ah, I think I misconstrued your point the first time around. Yes, I agree, it does seem to be a convergence issue, only it's very consistent hence my reluctance to label it as random, per se.. Perhaps I still have some misunderstanding.
Also, it's worth noting that the results seem be erroneous in #3. the accuracy for the 17th and 18th entry do not match up with the confusion matrix. I'm not sure what happened there, but I figured I'd point it out, just in case, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class Weight can be important even for balanced data if, for example, some class is more significant than others, so loss wrt this class should count more.

One can even think of class weights as **unique extra hyper-parameters** with their own effect on the outcome (either positive or negative) and treat them as such **without interpretation**.

Related: [How does class_weight work in Decision Tree?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90939/how-does-class-weight-work-in-decision-tree)

Comment: I had assumed as much, thanks for confirming. Mathematically speaking, it's seems I understand what is happening, which implies I merely don't understand why this is the case for this particular dataset. My intuition provokes me to believe that the model holding the normal cases as "more important" leads it to classify pneumonia cases as normal cases with some form of anomaly. Does that seem a reasonable justification for the behaviour?

Comment: Further, I don't suppose you would have an idea of any examples where class weights are applied on balanced data that I could study? My google searches so far have only returned inbalance as a justification for their use.

Comment: I dont have some examples handy but I  agree with your conclusion that importance is what is at issue here. For example pneumonia can be deadly so it is only reasonable. However only the original authors can authenticaly explain its use

Comment: That's okay, I'll keep looking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But the accuracy score shouldn't care about cost-based metrics like this, should it?

Comment: @BenReiniger, can you explain a bit your comment, or give an example? A tentative answer I can give is that accuracy is affected since class weights affect the classification result thus accuracy, one way or another.

Comment: I mean the class weights affect the predictions, mainly in pulling predicted probabilities towards the higher-weighted class.  So your accuracy for the higher-weighted class will improve, but the accuracy among the lower-weighted class should be lower (roughly).  But "importance" of the two classes isn't seen in that.  This answer seems to say more about how a cost-based metric may improve by weighting a costlier type of error, but it doesn't seem to address why accuracy would be better after weighting?

Comment: @BenReiniger, this is not necessarily so especialy if the data are "skewed" or correlated in some way (leaving out imbalance). This is again a tentative answer I can think of. The OP does not clarify where the accuracy improved in training or in test.

Comment: To clarify, the drop in accuracy seems to only be in validation accuracy, I think it's also affecting loss during training also. I have also ensured that the data is balanced in the model by enforcing an equal number of data for each class in the code.

Having done some further reading, the class weights should only really affect the model in the earlier stages of training, the longer the training the less impact those weights should have. This is leading me to believe there is something important being inferred here about the data but I'm still unsure of what specifically that is.

Comment: Just to give some reference for my "the class weights should only really affect.." comment, http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/byrd19a/byrd19a.pdf